# How to construct a network from a file of edges

Tags: r, networking

I have the following file:

```
Apple   Pear

Apple   Raspberry

Raspberry   Pear

Lemon   Pear

Lime    Plum

Pineapple   Grape
```

As output, I'd like a list of chains of fruits--on each line, associate any two fruits that ever appear together on a line, e.g., one line would be Pineapple, Grape because each appears once and only once, together.

I'm looking for the following output:

```
Apple Pear Raspberry Lemon

Lime Plum

Pineapple Grape
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: what languages are you comfortable with?

Comment: Unix preferably, I have some perl/python too. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I mean if there is a duplicate of any column in any line then the lines should be merged (Eg Apple in lines 1 and 2, raspberry in lines 2 and 3, and Pear in lines, 1, 3 and 4 merge to one line with Lemon as it is on the same line as Pear in line 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're basically after creating a network of the fruits, so you're best off using the `network` package (which I just learned about in answering this question, so it's probably got all sorts of functionality I don't understand yet).

To read that text, use `read.table(text=...)`:

```
x<-read.table(text="Apple   Pear

Apple   Raspberry

Raspberry   Pear

Lemon   Pear

Lime    Plum

Pineapple   Grape")
```

Then simply create a `network` object from `x`:

```
library(network)
net<-network(x)
```

For example, you can plot the network:

```
plot(net)
```

[image: network (unlabelled)]

Haven't quite figured out how to get your exact desired output, but you can see in the plot above that we've achieved the association you wanted. Not sure your end goal, but check out some tutorials for `network`.